# Recuperar dados/textos de outros sites com PHP

Tags: php

Tem como recuperar dados de outros sites com php?

Do tipo, eu gostava de fazer um site de streaming e queria que as classificações do video (ou assim) estivessem sempre a ser atualizadas em relação ao imbd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, normalmente estes sites criam APIs para que outros sites peguem as informações com a utilização de Web Services.

Encontrei esta API que retorna a classificação de uma série ou filme:

http://www.omdbapi.com/

Normalmente retornam um JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) e no PHP utilizamos os métodos json_encode($objeto) e json_decode($json) para manipular o JSON.

Exemplo:

Link utilizado:

```
 http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Game%20of%20Thrones&Season=1&Episode=1
```

JSON retornado:

> {"Title":"Winter Is Coming","Year":"2011","Rated":"TV-MA","Released":"17 Apr 2011","Season":"1","Episode":"1","Runtime":"62 min","Genre":"Adventure, Drama, Fantasy","Director":"Timothy Van Patten","Writer":"David Benioff (created by), D.B. Weiss (created by), George R.R. Martin (\"A Song of Ice and Fire\" by), David Benioff, D.B. Weiss","Actors":"Sean Bean, Mark Addy, Nikolaj Coster-Waldau, Michelle Fairley","Plot":"Jon Arryn, the Hand of the King, is dead. King Robert Baratheon plans to ask his oldest friend, Eddard Stark, to take Jon's place. Across the sea, Viserys Targaryen plans to wed his sister to a nomadic warlord in exchange for an army.","Language":"English","Country":"USA","Awards":"N/A","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk5MDU3OTkzMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTc0ODg5NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg","Metascore":"N/A","imdbRating":"8.4","imdbVotes":"13098","imdbID":"tt1480055","seriesID":"tt0944947","Type":"episode","Response":"True"}

PHP:

```
<?php

    /* Retorna um JSON de String a partir do método file_get_contents 
    e decodifica esta String de JSON a partir do método json_decode para manipular no PHP. */

    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Game%20of%20Thrones&Season=1&Episode=1'));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acesso direto aos dados de um site que não tenha um API ou web service é bem díficil (e poderia ser até fraude). O @Giancarlo mencionou uma solução muito boa, sendo esse acesso a um API.

Muitos sites tem ou dão acesso aos dados com um API. Normalmente há direções, tutoriais, e documentação sobre como acessar esses APIs, e as informações que formacerão.

Comment: Sim, consegui fazer o que queria pelo que o @Giancarlo me disse :)